# How to postpone a skype interview by a potential supervisor if you are not fully prepared? Is it advisable to postpone?

Tags: interview

How to postpone a skype interview by a potential supervisor if you are not fully prepared? Is it advisable to postpone, if you are only prepared some, and are not fluent in talking your research since English is not the first language.